# Default value for variable arguments in scala method

Tags: scala, default-value

I want to define a default value for a variable argument parameter in a Scala method. Is it possible?

```
def aMethod(variableArguments: String* = ???){}
```

I have tried using `variableArguments:String* = Seq("a","b","c"):_*` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler error makes it pretty clear-cut:

> :10: error: a parameter section with a `*'-parameter is not allowed to have default arguments

You can work around this with overloading, if you wish:

```
def test(a: String*): String = a.mkString
def test(): String = test("a", "b", "c")
```